# whether Session state is suitable for my Condition?

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

I am doing a Project with 2 different modules which is Admin and Customer . Here is the confusion in Customer Module,In Customer Module what i have to do is I have to maintain the Customer ID in each page of customer Module.which means customer module have Different Report Forms ,Entry forms,etc. 
If the Customer is Logged in i want to show name in every page.In reports section i want to show only the related data of Logged in customers.
In every report i want to show only related data of logged in Customer details.
so i have choosed to use `Session state` in every page.Is this a good way ? Am i doing right ? i used session in every page load ?Is there any best option to do is? Guide me

sample  of my code

```
//Check weather session variable null or not
if (Session["UserName"] != null)
{
    //Retrieving UserName from Session
    lblWelcome.Text = "Welcome : " + Session["UserName"];
}
```

Thanks

Comment: While you can use the session to roll your own authentication mechanism, you would be better off to use a pre-built tested system such as "Forms Authentication".

Comment: could you refer any article to implement it? @Matthew

Comment: session variable is needed here, it would be good if you do this checking in the master page instead of writing it again and again in every page load event.

Comment: Yes i did in Master Page but in Report page i have to bind the data based on logged in Customers. @yogihosting

Comment: yes you will have to do it since http is stateless. See my answer too.

Answer (score 0):

It will be better to keep a class object in session like this -

```
class Employee
{
    public EId {get; set;}
    public EName {get; set;}
    public Employee(){}
}
```

Store the class object in session -

```
Employee emp = new Employee();
Session["EmployeeObj"] = emp;
```

Sometimes storing session in sql server becomes handy too, see http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/104082/Configuring-ASP-session-state-on-SQL-server
thanks